# Синхронизация в console

Tags: c#, консоль

В консольном приложении есть код, отвечающий за вывод на экран красивой анимации роботы программы. Помимо этого производится определенная полезная работа.
Как синхронизировать эти два процесса так, чтобы они заканчивались одновременно?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

msdn пример:

```
using System;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

class WaitAllDemo
{
    // Demonstrated features:
    //      Task.Factory
    //      Task.Result
    //      Exception handling
    // Expected results:
    //      10 tasks are started, each passed an index as a state object.
    //      The tasks that receive an argument between 2 and 5 throw exceptions.
    //      Task.WaitAll() wraps all exceptions in an AggregateException and propagates it to the main thread.
    // Documentation:
    //      http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.taskfactory_members(VS.100).aspx
    static void Main()
    {
        // Define a delegate that prints and returns the system tick count
        Func<object, int> action = (object obj) =>
        {
            int i = (int)obj;

            // Make each thread sleep a different time in order to return a different tick count
            Thread.Sleep(i * 100);

            // The tasks that receive an argument between 2 and 5 throw exceptions
            if (2 <= i && i <= 5)
            {
                throw new InvalidOperationException("SIMULATED EXCEPTION");
            }

            int tickCount = Environment.TickCount;
            Console.WriteLine("Task={0}, i={1}, TickCount={2}, Thread={3}", Task.CurrentId, i, tickCount, Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);

            return tickCount;
        };

        const int n = 10;

        // Construct started tasks
        Task<int>[] tasks = new Task<int>[n];
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            tasks[i] = Task<int>.Factory.StartNew(action, i);
        }

        // Exceptions thrown by tasks will be propagated to the main thread
        // while it waits for the tasks. The actual exceptions will be wrapped in AggregateException.
        try
        {
            // Wait for all the tasks to finish.
            Task.WaitAll(tasks);  <=== вот это то что вам нужно

            // We should never get to this point
            Console.WriteLine("WaitAll() has not thrown exceptions. THIS WAS NOT EXPECTED.");
        }
        catch (AggregateException e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("\nThe following exceptions have been thrown by WaitAll(): (THIS WAS EXPECTED)");
            for (int j = 0; j < e.InnerExceptions.Count; j++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("\n-------------------------------------------------\n{0}", e.InnerExceptions[j].ToString());
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Очень интересно.
А какую литературы Вы можете рекомендовать почитать по теме?

Comment: @DisguisePerceptron почитайте Рихтера.

Comment: Спасибо за совет